# Unable to find API filter in Istio Response Latency Metric using GCP Monitoring

Tags: monitoring, kubernetes-helm, istio, latency, google-cloud-stackdriver

In GCP Monitoring we have metric called **istio.io/service/server/response_latencies** by which we could able to get Response latency.

But we have a service which will perform around 4 API call which should be group together during filtering with response latency so that we can get it in the graph of GCP Monitoring.

Unfortunately we have the metric in GCP Monitoring but could not able to find the **restAPI filter** for the same.

Below is the describe command for that specific metric. Please confirm how to integrate the API calls that my app is doing in the server-response-latency metric.

```
$kubectl describe instance.config.istio.io/server-response-latencies -n istio-system

Name:         server-response-latencies
Namespace:    istio-system
Labels:       app=istio-telemetry
Annotations:  <none>
API Version:  config.istio.io/v1alpha2
Kind:         instance
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2020-08-14T15:47:10Z
  Generation:          4
  Resource Version:    14279845
  Self Link:           /apis/config.istio.io/v1alpha2/namespaces/istio-system/instances/server-response-latencies
  UID:                 49c42e39-1xxx-xxx-addde-2dddddd323234f
Spec:
  Compiled Template:  metric
  Params:
    Dimensions:
      api_name:                        api.service | "unknown"
      api_version:                     api.version | "unknown"
      destination_owner:               destination.owner | "unknown"
      destination_port:                destination.port | 0
      destination_principal:           destination.principal | "unknown"
      destination_service_name:        destination.service.name | "unknown"
      destination_service_namespace:   destination.service.namespace | "unknown"
      destination_workload_name:       destination.workload.name | "unknown"
      destination_workload_namespace:  destination.workload.namespace | "unknown"
      request_operation:               conditional((context.protocol | "unknown") == "grpc", request.path | "unknown", request.method | "unknown")
      request_protocol:                context.protocol | "unknown"
      response_code:                   response.code | 0
      service_authentication_policy:   conditional((context.reporter.kind | "inbound") == "outbound", "unknown", conditional(connection.mtls | false, "mutual_tls", "none"))
      source_owner:                    source.owner | "unknown"
```

Note : we are performing the deployment using Helm charts.

Answer (score 0):

According to Cloud Monitoring API
documentation [page](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/v3#api_concepts):

> #### Filters
>
> The Monitoring API v3 uses filters to select metrics, to fetch
> time-series data, and to collect monitored resources into groups. For
> more information, see  [Monitoring
> filters](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/v3/filters).
>
> The Monitoring API v3 also uses filters to restrict the result set of
> certain  `list`  operations. See  [Sorting and
> filtering](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/v3/sorting-and-filtering)
> for details on managing the results of the
> [`alertPolicies.list`](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.alertPolicies/list)
> and
> [`notificationChannels.list`](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.notificationChannels/list)
> methods.

And in here you can find guide how to use [filters](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/v3/filters#overview):

> You can use filters in the  [Monitoring API
> v3](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest)  to do the
> following:
>
> - **Retrieve time series**. Use a filter to select  [time series data](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/v3/metric-model#time-series)
>   based on the data's project, group, monitored resource properies, and
>   metric properties. For more information and examples, see  [Retrieving
>   time series
>   data](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/v3/filters#time-series-filter).
> - **Define the resources in a group**. Use a filter to assign resources to a
>   [`Group`](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.groups#Group)
>   based on the resources' properties and the project to which they
>   belong. For more information and examples, see  [Defining group
>   membership](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/v3/filters#group-filter).
> - **List group members**. Use a filter to select resources within a group based on the resources' properties and the project to which they
>   belong. For more information and examples, see  [Listing group
>   members](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/v3/filters#group-member-filter).
> - **List metric descriptors**. Use a filter to inspect particular metric types from the hundreds of defined types in Monitoring. For
>   more information and examples, see  [Listing metric
>   descriptors](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/v3/filters#metric-descriptor-filter).
> - **List monitored resource descriptors**. Use a filter to inspect particular monitored resource types from the dozens of defined types
>   in Monitoring. For more information and examples, see  [Listing
>   monitored resource
>   descriptors](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/v3/filters#mr-filter).

You can create a filter that defines the resources in a group.

Note that According to GCP [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_istio#istio-istio) the `service/server/response_latencies` metric is still in beta stage and there are couple of issues related to this in istio versions prior to `1.5`.